# How to wait if event received before some action in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-handling

I have a class in which a method is called on the basis of events received from external application.

```
public void ProcessItems(Store id,Items items)
{
    //Some logic
     UpdateValidItems(id,validItems)

}

public void UpdateValidItems(Store id,Items items)
{
        //Save in DB
}
```

The external application may invoke "ProcessItems" while UpdateValidItems is being processed. I want that if UpdateValidItems is being processed and event invoked during UpdateValidItems processing then it should wait until UpdateValidItems completed. Is there any way to do it?

Also, multiple stores can be processed at a time. So it should wait for store based only. If storeId is different then it should not wait.

Comment: Is the usage of a lock() an option?

Comment: We can use lock.

Comment: Check the answer i posted below. It contains an example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd decouple incoming Events and processing:

1. Have a thread wait on a [Blocking Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8)
2. Event writes to Blocking Queue
3. Thread from 0.) gets notified, dequeues 1 "Row" (Id and Items)
4. Said Thread processes the Items
5. Thread waits again OR if meanwhile the Event added more Rows: Process until queue is empty, then wait again.

This ensures that:

- Only one Store is mutated at a time
- Event returns fast
- Following events for same store do not interfere with current processing.

You may also have a look into [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) to implement a similar approach.

---

Edit / Basic Example:

```
public class Handler
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<QueueEntry> _queue = new BlockingCollection<QueueEntry>();
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // I used a Form with a button to simulate events, so you'll have to adapt that..
    public Handler(Form1 parent)
    {
        // register for incoming Items
        parent.NewItems += Parent_NewItems;
        // Start processing on a long running Pool-Thread
        Task.Factory.StartNew(QueueWorker, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    // Stop Processing
    public void Shutdown( bool doitnow )
    {
        // Mark the queue "complete" - adding is now forbidden.
        _queue.CompleteAdding();
        // If you want to stop NOW, cancel all operations
        if (doitnow ) { _cts.Cancel(); }
        // Else the Task will run until the queue has been processed.
    }

    // This is all that happens on the EDT / Main / UI Thread
    private void Parent_NewItems(object sender, NewItemsEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            _queue.Add(new QueueEntry { Sender = sender, Event = e });
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // dontcare ? I didn't - You may, though.
            // Will be thrown if the queue has been marked complete.
        }
    }

    private async Task QueueWorker()
    {
        // While the queue has not been marked complete and is empty
        while (!_queue.IsCompleted)
        {
            QueueEntry entry = null;
            try
            {
                // Wait until an entry is available or until canceled.
                entry = _queue.Take(_cts.Token); 
            }
            catch ( OperationCanceledException )
            {
                // dontcare
            }
            if (entry != null)
            {
                await Process(entry, _cts.Token);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task Process(QueueEntry entry, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        // Dummy Processing...
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(entry.Event.Items), cancel);
    }
}

public class QueueEntry
{
    public object Sender { get; set; }
    public NewItemsEventArgs Event { get; set; }
}
```

Of, course, this can be tuned to allow for some concurrency / parallel processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
private object lock_object = new object();

public void ProcessItems(Store id,Items items)
{
    //Some logic

    lock(lock_object)
    {
        UpdateValidItems(id,validItems)
    }    
}
```

Comment: Should we use this lock in multiple methods?

Comment: @umer Given your requirements, I don't think `lock` will make you happy.

Comment: @Fildor Then what makes me happy?

Comment: @umer See my answer ;)

Comment: The lock will help to ensure the method is collade sequential. It holds the call on a new event intil the lock is released. IMHO it matches the requirements perfectly.

Comment: @umer You should use the lock here to preserve the execution of the method UpdateValidItems. This is sufficient to prevent simultanious execution of this method

Comment: One drawback of the lock will be that it will block your Main Thread until the Update is done. More often than not you'd want to block your event handling thread as shortly as possible.